# How many different sets can be formed by two nonempty sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If A and B are two different nonempty sets, how many distinct sets can be formed
with these sets using as many unions,intersections,complements and parentheses as desired.

Four sets are fundamental:$A$,$B$,$A \cup B$,$A \cap B$.

Other sets are $A \cup B'$,$A' \cup B$,$A \cap B'$,$A' \cap B$,$A' \cup B'$,$A' \cap B'$.
Any other sets are possible.

Comment: You could look at cartesian products and power sets.

Comment: @Trevor:Sorry,cartesian products and power sets are not allowed.

Comment: To get a clear answer, you have to assume that A and B are not just distinct but also "as independent as possible" in some sense. Otherwise, it could be the case that A = {1} and B = {1,2}, and you only get 8 possible sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$16$.  The corresponding Venn diagram has four parts, and you can get any combination of those four parts.

Comment: @Yuan:Is there a formula for that.Is it 2^(2^n) where n is the number of distinct sets.

Comment: @Vinod: yes, that sounds about right.

Comment: @Vinod $2^{2^n - 1}$ to be accurate.