# Characterisation of linearly separable points of a hypercube

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry, decision-problems

Essentially, *linearly separable* points are just those corners that can be cut off with just **one slice** as marked out by a hyperplane.

E.g. for a cube, the following 4 points (red) are **not** linearly separable - no single cut by a plane (tilted at whatever angle) across the cube can slice off exactly these 4 points:

[image]

So this begs the question: given $n$ points on an $m$-dimensional hypercube, how can I tell if these $n$ points are linearly separable?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh - thanks, sounds like that might be what I want, but what is $p_i - p_0$?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I think I misread the question. $p_i-p_0$ just means the vector pointing from the point $p_0$ to the point $p_i$.

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18056/how-many-presentable-boolean-functions-with-n-attributes-are-linear-separable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a crucial problem in machine learning, much studied since the 60's and there is no easy characterisation or criterion - nor even efficient algorithms. See eg [this](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Emegiddo/pdf/hegedus.pdf) and [this](http://www.lcc.uma.es/%7Elfranco/A23-Subirats+Jerez+Franco08.pdf), , and references, or google for "Threshold Logic".